# Manipulating behavior with External Attribution

Tags: attribution

A quick background on me. I am a mid level software engineer at a mid sized and growing software company (200+ engineers)

I want to help our company's development department by encouraging the idea of craftsmanship and pride amongst the other engineers.

My plan to do this is through behavior manipulation by applying a new external attribution. I am currently writing a paper on this for my company but I can only find negative examples of external attribution.

My question is, is there any research that anyone can point me toward that validates changing behavior through external attribution. (I've already gone through the stanford experiment)

Comment: At the moment the question is difficult to understand because the rationale is unclear. Why should (whose?) external attribution (of what?) lead to what (exactly?) you want? My feeling is that you mean something different by the term "external attribution" than it is used in psychology. (External attribution = the belief that a behavior has been caused by factors outside of a person/i.e., the situation).

Comment: I want to create a club or group that would encourage employees to be craftsmen. That's the external situation

Comment: 'External attribution' is not what you are looking for. Maybe you're trying to create or increase a sense of social identity, see here e.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=3n9IAwAAQBAJ&dq=social+identity+at+work